# During CSV import in Prestashop, an empty image is generated, despite thumbnail regeneration being enabled

Tags: csv, import, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a weird problem.
During the CSV file import using [PrestaShop's default function](https://docs.prestashop-project.org/1.7-documentation/user-guide/configuring-shop/advanced-parameters/import) (attempting to import a product), I enable the 'Regenerate thumbnails' option. Despite this, after importing, an empty image is generated for the product. From what I've noticed, the only solution I've managed to find is to ignore the column with images, but then when a new product is added (to my CSV), it won't have an image.

Tried searching for same problem on the internet, but found nearly nothing. Just one case, with very old PrestaShop, and the problem was not much similar.